# jquery: fade in image after image

Tags: jquery, list, fade

I have a page with 10 images in and I want to fade them in one after another once the image has been downloaded. how can I detect the image is loaded and ready to be displayed? and should I loop through the loaded images fadeIn and once fadedIn wait for the next to load?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the load() event on an image. E.g.

```
$('#some_image').hide()
    .load(function () {
      $(this).fadeIn();
    })
    .attr('src', 'images/headshot.jpg')
```

Comment: so will the load function only execute when the image has fully downloaded?

Comment: Yes, it happens when the image is loaded.

Comment: You can see it in action here: http://jsbin.com/ejesu/edit (for as long as jsbin keeps the snippet).

Answer (score 0):

You can preload the images maybe ([See here](http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jpreload.htm)) and then call the the fadein and fadeout methods sequentially in a loop.

Comment: got the preload part working but i dont want to fade the image in until I know its been preloaded?

Comment: You can use the onLoad event of the image object you just loaded like so: objImage.onLoad=imagesLoaded();.  The imagesLoaded function is called after the image is loaded.  Put your fadein fadeout stuff in there.

Answer (score 0):

*(Based on Kris Erickson's answer)*

You may be able to avoid potential race conditions by adding the event to the image before adding it to the DOM (unconfirmed but I like to play it safe). Also this method is good for fading images on top of each other.

This is what I'm using for a gallery control where I add an image on top of another image and fade it in - then I remove the bottom image if I've already added 2 images.

```
var url = .....;
var container = $('#images_container');

$("<img />").hide().load(function () {
    $(this).fadeIn(); 
}).attr('src', url).appendTo($(container ));

if ($(container).children().length > 2) {
    $(":nth-child(1)", container).remove();
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="images_container"></div>
```

The CSS must be set up like this or the images will stack instead of being on top of each other.

```
#images_container {
   position: relative;
}

#images_container {
   position: absolute;
}
```