# load but also display the image in jquery

Tags: jquery

I found this post about how to fade images in jquery:

[jquery: fade in image after image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294513/jquery-fade-in-image-after-image)

But I am not sure how to do this as I first need to load lets say four images:

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
4.jpg
```

So I have four jpeg images, and I want to fade in and out from them every say 30 seconds.
How do I first load them into my page and then fade in and out of each one in jquery

Answer (score 1):

as I understand you would like to make a cycle. First display image 1, then image 2, then 3, 4 and again 1, 2...

You might be interested in [cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)

to insert image you use img tag, the example code looks like this:

```
   <img src="path/to/your/image.jpg" alt="description of your image" width="100" height="100" />
```

alt is important, because it will be displayed if the picture will not be loaded (for exmaple someone has disabled displaying images). It is also important for searches. Width and height is important, because your website will not be resized after loading the picture, but imiedietely will reserve some space. you can then do something like:

```
   $('image').hide() .load(function () { $(this).fadeIn(); })
```

However, the link, which I have provided includes all necessary example to do exactly what you need, plus a couple of more nice ways to tackle your problems

Comment: it doesnt matter which picture comes up, i just have 4 pictures and I want to know how to load them and display them (guys please post code as I am new to this).

Comment: +1 I foudn some examples on the site that looks promising, I may accept your answer, but sometimes its nice to see people come up with their code so I will hold off but thank you so far...

Comment: Ok, to insert image you use <img> tag, the example code looks like this:

<img src="path/to/your/image.jpg" alt="description of your image" width="100" height="100" />

alt is important, because it will be displayed if the picture will not be loaded (for exmaple someone has disabled displaying images). It is also important for searches. Width and height is important, because your website will not be resized after loading the picture, but imiedietely will reserve some space. 
you can then do something like:

$('image').hide()
    .load(function () {
      $(this).fadeIn();
    })